# Why does locking the JavaScript thread also lock the UI?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I understand JavaScript is single-threaded and its performance can suffer if not used properly, but I'm having difficulty connecting that to UI freezes in the browser. JavaScript itself is not rendering the UI, is it?

Something as simple as:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
    <script>
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        while (true) {}
      }, 5000);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>Hello</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

will freeze up in 5 seconds, whereafter clicking the button doesn't cause its pressed state to show. Why do browsers handle JavaScript in this way? Would it not make more sense to just let JavaScript spin away and have unrelated actions continue, unaffected?

Comment: When a button is clicked, several javascript events are fired. These events cannot be processed until any currently running javascript completes. How these events are handled (including cancelling the event) can change how the button behaves. Running the default actions and then, later, running the javascript actions doesn't make sense when that javascript has the option of preventing the default action.

Comment: The button itself doesn't have any JavaScript event handlers connected to it, though? Not that I added, at least. I would think the browser could be smart about it and not block elements it knows don't have any handlers.